# After git cvsimport, how to map cvs file revision numbers to a git commit hash?

Tags: git, cvs

I'm in the process of converting several large CVS repositories to git repositories.  I've run  git cvsimport, now I need to update some in-house tools that rely on the cvs revision numbers. The revision numbers are significant in that they are stored in a database to track which versions of particular files have been deployed.  I need to update file revision numbers in the database with the corresponding commit hash in the cvsimport'ed git repository.  Is there any way to take any arbitrary revision number for any file, and figure out the git commit hash that particular change was made on?

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use the "-R" option in git cvsimport:

```
       -R
       Generate a $GIT_DIR/cvs-revisions file containing a mapping from CVS revision numbers to newly-created Git commit
       IDs. The generated file will contain one line for each (filename, revision) pair imported; each line will look like

           src/widget.c 1.1 1d862f173cdc7325b6fa6d2ae1cfd61fd1b512b7
```

My version of git with that option is 1.7.0.4